Обобщение темы: выбор вариантных окончаний А/Ы для существительных мужского рода в И.п. мн. числа
Вопрос задан  по [недавнему вопросу][1], также он обсуждался и раньше. Я считаю, что пересказ различных материалов не дает общего представления об этой теме, что мешает ее пониманию.
В то же время тема актуальна и постоянно присутствует в экзаменационных вопросах и тестах.

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

ТЕОРИЯ
О различении окончаний А/Я и Ы/И  в форме И.п. мн. числа
При желании в этой теме можно утонуть, но лучше этого не делать. Как же поступить?
(1) Нужно иметь общее представление о проблеме (взгляд сверху), тогда не так страшно.
(2) Желательно не заниматься статистикой, иначе реакция такая: Ужас!  Как всё это иностранцы изучают?! Тогда носители снисходительно говорят: "Ну это их проблемы".
(3) Но и у носителей языка в этой теме вопросов тоже хватает, поэтому надо  выделить наиболее проблемную зону: выбор А/Ы для односложных и двусложных сущ. м. рода с твердыми окончаниями.
(4) Во всех прочих случаях: слушаем грамотную речь и используем словарь при затруднении.
1. ОБЩАЯ КАРТИНА. История форм множественного числа
В древнерусском языке было 6 склонений, которые различались по древним основами (на А, О, У, И и на согласный), также было двойственное число. Во всех числах склонения  различались. Ужас!
В современном русском языке три типа склонения различаются по падежам только в ед.числе; во мн. же числе имеется по существу единое склонение: в трех падежах одинаковые окончания (ам, ами, ах, кроме И.п., Р.п. В.п.  Но эти различия определяются в основном не типом склонения, а характером основы и (иногда) лексическими факторами. // Спасибо за унификацию!
До 17 в. формы на ударяемое -а/я практически не встречаются (искл. колокола, леса). Редки они и в памятниках 18 в.
В настоящее время окончание -а/я становится продуктивным. Увы! Часто  вариантные формы -а/ы различаются стилистически (формы на -а разговорные), а иногда семантически (учители и учителя).
ПРИЧИНЫ распространения форм на а/я не совсем ясны (как вариант, под влиянием существительных среднего рода или двойственного числа). // Вероятно, наше "коллективное сознание" в те времена решило, что окончание на -а/я в мужском роде еще пригодится))
Из статьи  История склонения имен существительных
  существительные 
  - типа БЕРЕГА восходят к форме И.-В.п. 
  двойственного числа. склонения на *-ŏ (мужского 
  рода); 
  - типа ГОСПОДА, БРАТЬЯ  восходят  к  форме  И.п.  
  ед.ч.  собирательных существительных   женского   
  рода,   которые   стали   восприниматься   как 
  существительные мужского рода во множественном 
  числе;

2. СТАТИСТИКА ВАРИАНТОВ
На учебных сайтах такая статистика приводится часто. В качестве справочного материала можно, например, посмотреть:
Именительный падеж существительных множественного числа.
Какое правило для окончаний существительных во множественном числе?
3. ПРОБЛЕМНАЯ ЗОНА (выбор А/Ы для сущ. м. рода с твердыми окончаниями).
Перечень основных окончаний А/Я и Ы/И (мн. число И.п)
    1-ое склонение: стЕны, зЕмли – окончание Ы/И 
    2-ое склонение, мужской род: столы, жители – окончание 
    Ы/И 
    2-ое склонение, средний род: окна, поля – окончание А/Я 
    3-ье склонение: пЕчи – окончание И 

Итак, для сущ. м. рода на твердый согласный основным окончанием является Ы.   В то же время вариантное окончание А имеет значительное количество существительных м. рода. К ним относятся:
    (1) многие слова с односложной основой: бок – бока, лес 
     – леса, луг – луга, снег – снега;
    (2) некоторые слова с неодносложной основой (в этом 
    случае ударение обычно падает на второй слог от конца 
    основы): бЕрег – берегА, гОрод – городА, пАрус – парусА.
    Обычно только т а к о й тип ударения является основанием 
    для существования вариантных окончаний.
    ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ. Если неодносложные слова имеют другой тип 
    ударения, то окончание А/Я для них может быть 
    ненормативным, например: инженЕр – инженЕры (грубо 
    неправильно – инженерА).

4. КОГДА НУЖЕН СЛОВАРЬ
Выбор окончаний легко определяется на слух, если нет вариантов. Это может быть окончание как А, так и Ы. Если есть варианты, то слово вызывает повышенный интерес у экзаменаторов. Составьте для себя собственный  словарь со стилистическими пометками по словарям РАН (орфографическому или толковому).
Пример такого словаря (но его нужно проверять на Грамоте.ру, нормы могут меняться)
Основное внимание нужно уделить вариантным формам на А, которые как бы "понаехали". Их, кстати, меньше.
